# Underful hbox badness 10000

Tags: spacing, badness

A while back I ran across a web page that explained how to avoid this error by not using `\\` but hfill or hspace. I can't remember which one or find anything else about it. It was a very simple solution and solved the problem without extra packages or anything and simply filled the remaining horizontal space. Any ideas?

Comment: See [How to properly code a TeX file, or at least avoid badness 10000](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51722/5764) and [underfull `\hbox` (badness 10000) in paragraph](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41205/5764)

Comment: I saw that, it isn't what I'm talking about....

Comment: I downvoted your question, because I would suppose a user with 40 asked questions and 800 reputation to know how to ask a question. Your question is tough to answer, but not becuase the question is complicated, but the question is not properly written. You should have provided a minimal example, maybe some image of the page output or so.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Although it is difficult to adequately reproduce this *warning* (not an *error*), you may be after the TeX FAQ entry [No line here to end](http://texfaq.org/FAQ-noline). Here is one such a reproduction of the warning:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{description}
  \item[Very long label] Some starter text \\
    \\
    Here is some more text.
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

The problem stems from the use of `\\` to insert a blank line. Rather use a vertical skip (like `\smallskip`, `\medskip` or `\bigskip`) or leave a blank line - that would indicate a paragraph break and an associated "blank line". Alternatively, a resolution suggested is to provide an infinite stretch of space `\hspace*{\fill}` so that there's enough "to go around" for TeX to fill the line before breaking it.

Comment: Thanks, that was it... Forgot to use \fill. To be clear, it is "\\\hspace*{\fill}".