# weird underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph error

Tags: errors

I know this question has been asked dozen of times, but I cannot find any with a problem like mine:

I'm working on this document, which compiled fine yesterday (I still have the old version and it is still compiling perfectly), today I added a couple of sections and a bunch of subsections, without weird commands, only plain text and \\ but when I tried to compile I got dozens of underfull \hbox errors, the first one being at line 16 (which compiled fine in the previous version of the document).

This line, specifically, is:

> In linea di principio, una volta che un algoritmo è stato sviluppato, questo può essere eseguito, con risultati uguali e prevedibili tanto da un calcolatore quanto da un essere umano, con l'unica differenza che un calcolatore, a meno di errori (umani), nell'implementazione dell'algoritmo o dell'hardware su cui viene eseguito è decine di ordini di grandezza più veloce e più preciso a svolgere alcuni compiti.\\\\

that is, plain text ending with newlines.
the problem is that even after removing the newlines I still get the same error and I cannot understand what's causing it since it wasn't a problem yesterday.
How am I supposed to tell TeX to start a new line without it complaining?

Comment: never use `\\ ` at the end of a paragraph (or you will always get the error in the title) and never ever use `\\\\ ` at the end of a paragraph:-)

Comment: To end the paragraph use a blank line in the source.

Comment: take a look at this: [Implicit newline at the end of each paragraph?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66533/579) and also [Underful hbox badness 10000](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/54040/579)

Comment: @barbarabeeton the accepted answer there is remarkably similar to my comment here:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- that's why i just added a second link.

Comment: @barbara beeton: thanks, I'll try later, what I cannot understand is why the file from yesterday with the very same line 16 is compiling without problems

Comment: Also, as I said I already tried removing the \\\\ at the end of line 16, but it still gives the same errors, including the one on line 16

Comment: in your question, you said you added "a couple of sections and a bunch of subsections, without weird commands, only plain text and `\\ `" so i assumed that the double backslashes weren't there when you started.

Comment: @Alessandro a `\\ ` at the end of the paragraph will always make the warning you show but you can get it for other reasons as well, if you are then please make a _complete_ document from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` with (just) the paragraph making the warning then someone will be able to say why the warning occurs

Comment: if you leave a blank line -- or `\par` to indicate a paragraph break -- you will get a new line.  if you don't want it indented, you can use `\noindent`.

Comment: @Alessandro presumably it made the warnings but you did not notice. The markup you show above will always make a warning (and bad output) in latex.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I found out the compilation was failing because I had involuntarily deleted the \end{document}, however it bugs me that the compiler is telling me that the process exited normally while there are a lot of warnings (I can see them if I look in the errors menu, but I would have expected it to alert me, that's why I didn't notice all the warnings earlier)

Comment: @Alessandro the warnings are printed on the terminal and in the log file, if you are not shown them you are presumably using an editor/IDE that is hiding them, if so that is a failing of the editor and not anything LaTeX can do anything about.