# very bad underfull hbox

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, spacing, line-breaking, boxes

I would like to include a progress bar in my presentation and, when in draft mode, a page number below the progress bar. I have the code to do this, and it looks great, but I get one instance of this warning per frame:

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active
```

I'm hoping it's possible to avoid this warning somehow. Here is a minimized version of the progress bar/page number combo which demonstrates the warning:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
    \tikz\node[draw,minimum width=\textwidth-0.25ex]{};
    foo
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I've looked at many similar questions ([1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41205/16779), [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/149358/16779), [3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108740/16779), [4](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/145900/16779), [5](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60672/16779)), but they all seem to involve either manually-inserted line breaks or justified table text. Mine involves neither, so their solutions don't seem to help here.

What can I do to maintain the placement of the tikz node and the text under it in my example without generating so darn many warnings?

Comment: I get no Underfull box warning when I run your example (with texlive 2014)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Crazy, I could have sworn that gave me the error last I tried. But I agree it doesn't now. I've edited to add a critical `-0.25ex` to the `minimum width` that triggers the problem.

Comment: leave an empty line before `foo`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need *something* to fill up the line, on the last line of the paragraph there is `\parfillskip` (after the `foo` but on the line with the tikz if you don't make that full width you need to pad it out.

so

```
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
    \tikz{\node[draw,minimum width=\textwidth-0.25ex]{};}\hfill\break%
    foo
}
```

or as suggested in commenst you could make them separate paragraphs so both get `\parfillskip`

Comment: Just one brace away from a tikz solution...